# Task work item priorities

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, thread-priority

I have a multi-threaded application that has to perform 3 different categories of work items. Category **A** is the highest priority items, Category **B** items comes after **A** and Category **C** items comes after **B**. These work items are queued to thread pool using Tasks. Let's say, there are 10 category **C** items already in queue and then a category **B** item is added. In this case, I would like category **B** item to be processed before any of the category **C** item. Is there anyway of accomplishing this?

Comment: I'd think about a thread-safe list with a custom sorting

Comment: You can create your own queue for task, ill try and implement one.

Comment: @LuisFilipe I haven't really tried much yet. I was thinking about using Thread.Priority, however, googling suggest that its probably not a good idea. So I am looking to get some start point here.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx

Comment: from .net4.0+ use the collections under System.Collections.Concurrent.

Comment: do not use thread priority.

Comment: I would modify Luis's advice, as " in general, do not _raise_ thread priority" and in your particular scenario, do not use thread priority for your solution at all. You should use a "priority queue" (aka "prioritized queue"), which will dequeue items in priority order. There are lots of resources online describing this data structure. If you have some _specific_ trouble implementing it, then feel free to post a question about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it by creating your own queue process. This is just a code mockup.

Create an object like this

```
public class PrioritizableTask
{
    public PrioritizableTask(Task task, int taskPriority)
    {
        Task = task;
        Priority = taskPriority;
    }

    public int Priority { get; private set; }

    public Task Task { get; private set; }
}
```

And then create another collection class and implement a new method on it, something like this.

```
public class PrioritizableTasksCollection : IList<PrioritizableTask>
{
    private static readonly List<PrioritizableTask> runners = new List<PrioritizableTask>();

    public void Add(PrioritizableTask item)
    {
        runners.Add(item);
    }

    public Task GetNextPriority()
    {
        var priorityTask = runners.OrderBy(x => x.Priority).FirstOrDefault();
        return priorityTask != null ? priorityTask.Task : null;
    }
}
```

Consume like

```
PrioritizableTasksCollection executors = new PrioritizableTasksCollection();
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 4));
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 3));
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 7));
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 5));
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 1));
executors.Add(new PrioritizableTask(new Task(() => { }), 2));
Task executeNext = executors.GetNextPriority();
```

Implement your own deleting on the collection.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at your problem and i did not find a built-in thread-safe sorted collection.

So i built a basic thread-safe `SortedSet<int>` wrapper class.

**Sorted Set**

```
public class MyThreadSafeSortedSet
{
    private SortedSet<int> _set = new SortedSet<int>(new MyComparer());
    private readonly object _locker = new object();

    public void Add(int value)
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _set.Add(value);
        }
    }

    public int? Take()
    {
        lock (_locker)
        {
            if (_set.Count == 0)
                return null;
            var item = _set.First();
            _set.Remove(item);
            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

I built a custom comparer which prefers even numbers

```
public class MyComparer : Comparer<int>
{
    public override int Compare(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (y % 2 == 0)
                return x - y;
            else
                return -1;

        }
        else
        {
            if (y % 2 == 0)
                return 1;
            else
                return x - y;

        }
    }
}
```

And finally two threads. One to produce items; the other one to take them

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    MyThreadSafeSortedSet queue = new MyThreadSafeSortedSet();

    var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Task.Delay(100).Wait();
                var randomNumber = r.Next();
                queue.Add(randomNumber);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("I'm done adding");
        });
    var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            var delay = r.Next(500);
            Task.Delay(delay).Wait();

            var item = queue.Take();
            Console.WriteLine("Took: {0}", item);
            if (item == null)
                break;
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAll(task2);
}
```

You can change the specialized `SortedSet` and custom comparer for your own classes.

Hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

Please look my version of solution based on BinarySearch method of List class.

```
enum CategoryOfWorkItem: int { C = 0, B, A };

struct WorkItem : IComparer<WorkItem>
{
    public CategoryOfWorkItem Category;

    public int Compare(WorkItem x, WorkItem y)
    {
        return x.Category - y.Category;
    }

    public void AddTo(List<WorkItem> list)
    {
        int i = list.BinarySearch(this, this);
        if (i < 0) i = ~i;
        list.Insert(i, this);
    }
}
```

Example of usage

```
List<WorkItem> list = new List<WorkItem>();

Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            WorkItem item = new WorkItem();
            switch (rand.Next(0, 3))
            {
                case 0: item.Category = CategoryOfWorkItem.A; break;
                case 1: item.Category = CategoryOfWorkItem.B; break;
                case 2: item.Category = CategoryOfWorkItem.C; break;
            }

            lock (list)
            {
                item.AddTo(list);
            }

            Task.Delay(rand.Next(100, 1000)).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Put {0}", item.Category);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Putting finished.");
    });

Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        while (true)
        {
            WorkItem item;
            Task.Delay(rand.Next(500, 1000)).Wait();
            lock (list)
            {
                if (list.Count < 1) break;
                item = list[list.Count - 1];
                list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Get {0}", item.Category);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Getting finished.");
    }));
```